# Error : CallbackOnCollectedDelegate - how to find the exact collected item?

Tags: c#, exception, garbage-collection, delegation

After few minutes of successfull running I get this error in my application.

> A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type
>   'myApp!myApp.globalKeyboardHook+keyboardHookProc::Invoke'.

I know this is because the garbage collector has killed an object or something else and my code is still referring the same thing.

If that is the case which object or component is more likely to be collected by the GC. How can I overcome this error. (having a ref ??)

Since I cant figure out which part of the code is in responsible for this issue, I'm posting the complete class here. (I guess it has no issue with my other classes)

```
class globalKeyboardHook
    {
        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        IntPtr hInstance;
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        // Events
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;

        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            hook();
        }

        ~globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            unhook();
        }

        public void hook()
        {
            hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
        }

        public void unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                if (1 == 1)
                {
                    KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    {
                        KeyDown(this, kea);
                    }
                    if (kea.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
        }


        // DLL imports

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
```

You'll certainly have trouble finding the collected item, it is not visible in your program.  The C# language is a bit too friendly here.  You are relying on its syntax sugar to automagically create a delegate object for `hookProc`.  This code is compiled to:

```
    keyboardHookProc $unspeakable = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, $unspeakable, hInstance, 0);
```

Which is a problem in pinvoke, the garbage collector has no idea that the $unspeakable delegate object is actually being used by native code.  It can only see managed references to objects.  So it collects the object as soon as a gen #0 garbage collection occurs.  Kaboom when Windows makes the hook callback.

It is up to you to ensure that this delegate object cannot be collected.  Use GCHandle.Alloc().  Or the simple way, storing it in a variable explicitly.  Which is fine here since you let the finalizer destroy the hook:

```
    IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
    keyboardHookProc callback;

    public void hook()
    {
        if (callback != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Hook already installed");
        if (hInstance == IntPtr.Zero) hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        callback = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callback, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public void unhook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        callback = null;
    }
```